# position:sticky doesn't work together with display:flex on IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, sticky

I'm trying to make the `position: sticky` and `display: flex` properties work on Internet Explorer 11.

It works great on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but, surprise surprise; it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11.

```html
<div class="flexbox-wrapper">
  <div class="regular">
     This is the regular box
  </div>
  <div class="sticky">
     This is the sticky box
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.regular {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
}
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m0u72h7k/3/)

How to make it work on IE11?

I have tried to use the [StickyState](https://github.com/soenkekluth/sticky-state#readme) polyfill, without any result.

It is not a problem if the `position: sticky` or `display: flex` doesn't work on IE11 as they both work separately:

[Position: sticky; working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n9yLrh76/2/)

My main problem is that I want to have main content section and a sidebar menu next to it, that should be visible when scrolling. Using `position: fixed` is not an option here.

Comment: IE11 doesn't support `position: sticky`. https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: Flex works almost as it should on IE11, this is not the issue here

Comment: Both of those work separately, at least as it comes to basic support. But it doesn't seem to work combined.

Comment: I woul use waypoints for this until we get rid of ie 11: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

Comment: @gringo_dave Please add the solution as an answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to caniuse.com position: sticky is not supported in IE11 and display: flex have partial support because lots of bugs.

I don't have much experience with StickyState but I use [StickyBits](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits) and it works just fine.

**EDIT:**

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/n9yLrh76/5/)

```html
<div class="flexbox-wrapper">
  <div class="regular">
    This is the regular box
  </div>
  <div class="sticky" id="stickyEl">
    This is the sticky box
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
stickybits('#stickyEl');
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.regular {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;

}
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work now : https://jsfiddle.net/n9yLrh76/5/

Answer (score 0):

this is for display:flex

add this style to your flexbox-wrapper class :

```
.flexbox-wrapper {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      }
```

then

```
.regular {
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

The flex shorthand computes to flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis

Comment: Unfortunately this did not helped.